# How to get the Order Remote IP?

Tags: customer, order-grid, grid

Nope, `Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order->getRemoteIp()` doesn't work. It always gives me `null`.

By when I check `sales_flat_order` table I can see `remote_ip` field. I just only need to check if the order was placed manually by admin or by the customer since I need to mark 'admin-placed' orders on the **order grid** in Backend.

I saw that someone suggests to check `store_id` field. But it never is `0`. It's always equal to my real store ID.

Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I resolved the problem by:

```
protected function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getId());
    if(strlen($order->getRemoteIp()) > 0) {
        return $row->getRealOrderId();
    } else {
        return $row->getRealOrderId() . ' <img style="vertical-align:bottom;" src="'.$this->getSkinUrl('images/fam_user_edit.gif').'" alt="Order by Phone" />';
    }
}
```